# Grey Water Coming Out of Our Toilets, Sinks and Showers

Tags: plumbing

We have grey water coming out of our sinks, toilets and showers. I have noticed a funny smell a couple weeks prior to this from my shower, but I ignored it thinking it was nothing too major.

This first started when I came home. I turned on the sink to wash my hands and then all the sudden there was a gap in the water, kind of like extra air in the water and made a loud spurting noise, then all of the sudden grey smelly water came running out. Similar thing happened with the showers and toilets.

We have tried changing the water filter, and after running the water through the system, it resolved a tiny bit but still has grey water and a smell to it. Same results happened when we reset our water softener.

I would love to hear some feed back with this problem of ours. Thanks for reading, and please comment any thoughts about what the problem may be and any solution.

Comment: Where does your water supply come from?

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Our water taps into underground rivers called aquifers. I'm in Minnesota

Comment: @JakobLandgraf is this a muni supply or a private well?

Comment: And if on a well, what type: dug well, drilled, artesian? Do you have septic system? Where is it located in relation to your well? Where is your neighbour's septic located? What type of filters do you have? Do you get the same water if you try at a sample port or faucet before your filtration?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. There was lots of rust build up on the well walls. The build up of rust eventually fell down into the water giving it the grey look and smell.